# Socket/ZeroMQ – segmentation fault python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, segmentation-fault, zeromq

Purpose of work: transferring data from a php script to python

To solve this problem I decided to use socket (module “socket” for python and socket_create for php).

Then I ran into the problem that after 2-3 hours the script generates a fatal “segmentation fault” error. Again, it does not give out immediately after launch, but after a few hours of good work.
Error code and screenshot below: 
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjjqU.jpg

```
def Socket_Server_start():
    socket_finder = socket.socket()
    socket_finder.bind(('', 10999))
    socket_finder.listen(1000)
    while True:
        connect, addr = socket_finder.accept() #We accept incoming connections
        threading.Thread(target=NewConnect, args=(connect, addr,)).start() #Create a new thread for working with a socket
        del connect, addr
Socket_Server_start() #Start the socket server
```

After failing with socket, I decided to use ZerpMQ
The situation remained exactly the same (after several hours of work, the script crashed).
Error code and screenshot below: 
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI0yE.jpg

```
def Socket_Server_start():
    global client, messages
    context = zmq.Context()
    client = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER) #Create server
    client.bind("tcp://*:5556")
    poll = zmq.Poller()
    poll.register(client, zmq.POLLIN) #Listen clients
    while True:
        sockets = dict(poll.poll(1000))
        if sockets:
            identity = client.recv().decode() #ID client
            msg = client.recv().decode().split("|") #Message frm client
            #Unimportant lines of code
            if identity not in messages: #If a user with this ID has not connected before
                messages[identity] = [] #Add client ID to variable
                threading.Thread(target=NewConnect, args=(ZeroMQ(identity),)).start() #Starting a thread to work with a socket
            else:
                messages[identity].append(msg) #The client is already in the variable -> add a message
Socket_Server_start()
```

Comment: Do out shutdown/close the connection in `NewConnect`?

Comment: @rveerd Yes it is